# libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file while installing tensorflow in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed `cuda-8.0` and installed TensorFlow using:

```
sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

When I try `import tensorflow as tf`, it says:

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I think it is searching for `libcublas` in `cuda-9.0`
I purged `cuda-9.0` before installing `cuda-8.0`
Can someone please suggest what else might be the reason?

Comment: your tensorflow build is apparently expecting CUDA 9.0.   Not sure why you would remove that and install CUDA 8.0.  You should probably install CUDA 9.0, or switch to an older build of TF that was using CUDA 8.0

Comment: If you're installing via pip the latest versions (1.5+), you need CUDA 9.0 or 9.1

Comment: I tried installing tensoflow 1.4 and its still giving the same error

Comment: Tensorflow is unable to find a library. So, you should make sure it is actually available and figure out why TensorFlow cannot find it. Cuda documentation asks you to set some env var and so does TensorFlow (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64). Make sure all of them are set correctly. You can also run python under `strace` to see where it is looking for the library.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go back for your tensorflow version. I'm using **tensorflow 1.13** with **cuda 10.1**. The problem was related with old installations. I don't have **libcublas.so.9.0** in my directories. I'm using **cuda 10.1**, but it says the same error. if you've installed old version previously, make sure you've removed all old versions of tensorflow and cuda. you can call `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`, it will remove the current, but when you call `pip list | grep tensorflow`, there might be an old version installed in your pc. Remove it completely and install tensorflow-gpu again. Also make sure you've added your cuda installed path to **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. There are 2 issue related to this. Take a look at these solutions

[solution1](https://ai-pool.com/d/tensorflow_1_13_does_not_use_gpu) -
[solution2](https://ai-pool.com/d/importerror_libcublas_so_9_0)